# How to install the CLI when receiving "npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.16299"

Tags: command-line-interface

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.16299
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli@latest"
npm ERR! node v6.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo

npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:80
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\an89226\npm-debug.log
```